# Telerik RadGrid Setting Cell Value When Another is Changed Client Side

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a RadGrid where certain columns are in Batch Edit mode. I also have two columns that are dependent on the other's value (EstLengthFt & EstLengthRds). I need to update the EstLengthRds value when the EstLengthFt cell is edited and vice versa. 
The current function I have only updates the html and not the value. I need the value of the control to be updated and have it set in BatchEditChanged mode so I can save it.

I cannot do any postback as the edited values would be lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    function AllSetCellValue(sender, args) {
                var grid;
                var master;
                var selected;
                var row;
                var ft;
                var cell;
                var rods;
                if (args.get_columnUniqueName() == "EstLengthFt") {
                    grid = $find('<%=RadGridAll.ClientID%>');
                    master = grid.get_masterTableView();
                    selected = master.get_selectedItems();
                    row = selected[0];
                    ft = args.get_value();
                    cell = master.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "EstLengthRds");
                    rods = Math.round((ft * .060606060606) * 100) / 100;
                    cell.innerHTML = rods;
                }
                if (args.get_columnUniqueName() == "EstLengthRds") {
                    grid = $find('<%=RadGridAll.ClientID%>');
                    master = grid.get_masterTableView();
                    selected = master.get_selectedItems();
                    row = selected[0];
                    rods = args.get_value();
                    cell = master.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "EstLengthFt");
                    ft = Math.round((rods * 16.5) * 100) / 100;
                    cell.innerHTML = ft;
                 }
            }

<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGridAll" AllowMuliRowEdit="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowSorting="True"
                GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowMultiRowEdit="True" OnNeedDataSource="GridAll_NeedDataSource"
                OnBatchEditCommand="GridAll_BatchEditComand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" EnableLinqExpressions="False"
                OnHTMLExporting="GridAll_HTMLExporting">
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="PropId,RowDetailsId,SurveyId,TitleInitId,TitleSumId" CommandItemDisplay="None"
                    AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="False"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" TableLayout="Fixed" EditMode="Batch">
                    <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" OpenEditingEvent="Click" />
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PropertyNumber" HeaderText="Tract Number" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                            FilterControlWidth="100px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IndexNumber" HeaderText="Index Number" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="120px"
                            FilterControlWidth="80px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Type" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                            UniqueName="DisplayName">
                            <FilterTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Width="130px" EmptyMessage="All" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridPropTypeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                    OnItemsRequested="GridPropTypeCombo_ItemsRequested" AppendDataBoundItems="True" />
                            </FilterTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="Owner Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                            FilterControlWidth="100px" />
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthFt" HeaderText="Est ROW Length(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            FilterControlWidth="60px" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" UniqueName="EstLengthFt">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("EstLengthFt") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtEstLengthFt" Type="Number" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"/>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthRds" HeaderText="Est ROW Length(rds)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            FilterControlWidth="60px" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" UniqueName="EstLengthRds">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("EstLengthRds") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtEstLengthRds" Type="Number" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-Width="200px"
                            FilterControlWidth="160px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Legal" HeaderText="Legal Description" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="120px"
                            FilterControlWidth="80px" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PermWidthDd" DataField="PermWidthDd" HeaderText="Perm Width(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            FilterControlWidth="60px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("PermWidthDd") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbGridPermitFt"
                                    DataTextField="DDName" DataValueField="DDValue" Width="90px" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                    OnItemsRequested="GridPermitCombo_ItemsRequested" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Temp Width(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            FilterControlWidth="60px" UniqueName="TempWidthDd">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("TempWidthDd") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbGridTemFt"
                                    DataTextField="DDName" DataValueField="DDValue" Width="90px" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                    OnItemsRequested="GridTempCombo_ItemsRequested" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="TractClosedDate" HeaderText="Tract Closed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ServiceProviderName" HeaderText="Company Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="SurveyAssigned" HeaderText="Survey Assigned Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="SurveyPermDate" HeaderText="Permission Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="FieldWorkCompleteDate" HeaderText="Field Work Completed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="FinalPlatRecvdDate" HeaderText="Final Plat Received" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Title Work Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Title Status" DataField="StatusDd" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="DateLtcCompleted" HeaderText="Title Completed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TitleAgent" HeaderText="Title Agent Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="AgentAssignedDate" HeaderText="Agent Assigned Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                            FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                            DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" />
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings Selecting-AllowRowSelect="True">
                    <ClientEvents OnBatchEditSetCellValue="AllSetCellValue" />
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" FrozenColumnsCount="2" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True" />
                </ClientSettings>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the client-side API offered by the BatchEditingManager and see if you can put this together: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-batch-editing.html. The third section of this article treats the client-side API.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the OnValueChanging event in my comboBox template column.
I also added two hidden columns to store the original values so I could make a comparison and determine which cell was changed.
The only problem is that when the value is changed, the comboBox fires the OnValueChanging event again and creates a continuous loop. I added a .Set flag to the comboBox after changing the value to prevent this.  The following code solved my problem.

```
function AllConvertValue(sender, args) {
        var grid = $find('<%=RadGridAll.ClientID%>');
        var master = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var getRow = master.get_selectedItems()[0];
        var row = master.get_dataItems()[getRow._itemIndex];
        var cellFt = row.findControl("txtEstLengthFt");
        var cellRds = row.findControl("txtEstLengthRds");
        var oldFt = row.findControl("OldFtValue");
        var oldRds = row.findControl("OldRdsValue");
        if (cellFt != null && cellRds != null) {
            if (oldFt._value != cellFt._value) {
                var rods = (cellFt._value * 0.060606061).toFixed(2);
                if (cellRds.Set != true) {
                    cellRds.Set = true;
                    cellRds.set_value(rods);
                }
                if (oldRds.Set != true) {
                    oldRds.Set = true;
                    oldRds.set_value(cellRds._value);
                }
                if (cellFt.Set != true) {
                    cellFt.Set = true;
                    cellFt.set_value(cellFt._value);
                }
                if (oldFt.Set != true) {
                    oldFt.Set = true;
                    oldFt.set_value(cellFt._value);
                }
            }
            if (oldRds._value != cellRds._value) {
                var ft = (cellRds._value * 16.500033).toFixed(2);
                if (cellFt.Set != true) {
                    cellFt.Set = true;
                    cellFt.set_value(ft);
                }
                if (oldFt.Set != true) {
                    oldFt.Set = true;
                    oldFt.set_value(cellFt._value);
                }
                if (cellRds.Set != true) {
                    cellRds.Set = true
                    cellRds.set_value(cellRds._value);
                }
                if (oldRds.Set != true) {
                    oldRds.Set = true;
                    oldRds.set_value(cellRds._value);
                }
            }
            if (oldFt._value == cellFt._value && oldRds._value == cellRds._value) {
                cellFt.Set = false;
                cellRds.Set = false;
                oldFt.Set = false;
                oldRds.Set = false;
            }
        }
    }


<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGridAll" AllowMuliRowEdit="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowSorting="True"
            GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowMultiRowEdit="True" OnNeedDataSource="GridAll_NeedDataSource"
            OnBatchEditCommand="GridAll_BatchEditComand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" EnableLinqExpressions="False"
            OnHTMLExporting="GridAll_HTMLExporting">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="PropId,RowDetailsId,SurveyId,TitleInitId,TitleSumId" CommandItemDisplay="None"
                AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="False"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" TableLayout="Fixed" EditMode="Batch">
                <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Row" OpenEditingEvent="Click" />
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PropertyNumber" HeaderText="Tract Number" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="120px"
                        FilterControlWidth="80px" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IndexNumber" HeaderText="Index Number" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="110px"
                        FilterControlWidth="70px" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Type" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                        UniqueName="DisplayName" MaxLength="50">
                        <FilterTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Width="130px" EmptyMessage="All" AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridPropTypeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                OnItemsRequested="GridPropTypeCombo_ItemsRequested" AppendDataBoundItems="True" />
                        </FilterTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="Owner Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                        FilterControlWidth="100px" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthFt" HeaderText="Est ROW Length(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                        FilterControlWidth="100px" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" UniqueName="EstLengthFt">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("EstLengthFt") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtEstLengthFt" Type="Number" MaxLength="50" Width="130px"
                                ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="AllConvertValue" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthFt" UniqueName="OldFtValue" Display="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="OldFtValue" Type="Number" ReadOnly="True"
                                ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="AllConvertValue" Text='<%#Bind("EstLengthFt") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthRds" HeaderText="Est ROW Length(rds)" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                        FilterControlWidth="100px" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" UniqueName="EstLengthRds">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("EstLengthRds") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtEstLengthRds" Type="Number" MaxLength="50" Width="130px"
                                ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="AllConvertValue" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EstLengthRds" UniqueName="OldRdsValue" Display="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="OldRdsValue" Type="Number"
                                ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="AllConvertValue" Text='<%#Bind("EstLengthRds") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-Width="200px"
                        FilterControlWidth="160px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Legal" HeaderText="Legal Description" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AgentAssigned" HeaderText="Agent Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="AssignedDate" HeaderText="Assigned Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Width="130px"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" MaxLength="50">
                        <FilterTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" Width="120px" EmptyMessage="All" AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridStatusFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                OnItemsRequested="GridStatusCombo_ItemsRequested" AppendDataBoundItems="True" />
                        </FilterTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PermWidthDd" DataField="PermWidthDd" HeaderText="Perm Width(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                        FilterControlWidth="60px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("PermWidthDd") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbGridPermitFt"
                                DataTextField="DDName" DataValueField="DDValue" Width="90px" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                OnItemsRequested="GridPermitCombo_ItemsRequested" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Temp Width(ft)" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                        FilterControlWidth="60px" UniqueName="TempWidthDd">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("TempWidthDd") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbGridTemFt"
                                DataTextField="DDName" DataValueField="DDValue" Width="90px" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                                OnItemsRequested="GridTempCombo_ItemsRequested" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="TractClosedDate" HeaderText="Tract Closed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ServiceProviderName" HeaderText="Company Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="SurveyAssigned" HeaderText="Survey Assigned Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="SurveyPermDate" HeaderText="Permission Date" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="FieldWorkCompleteDate" HeaderText="Field Work Completed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="FinalPlatRecvdDate" HeaderText="Final Plat Received" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Title Work Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText="" ReadOnly="True"
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Title Status" DataField="TitleStatus" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="DateLtcCompleted" HeaderText="Title Completed" HeaderStyle-Width="170px"
                        FilterControlWidth="130px" PickerType="DatePicker" EmptyDataText=""
                        DataFormatString="<%$ Resources:WebResources,dateFormatGrid %>" MaxLength="50" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TitleAgentAssigned" HeaderText="Title Agent Assigned" HeaderStyle-Width="500px"
                        FilterControlWidth="150px" ReadOnly="True" MaxLength="50"/>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings Selecting-AllowRowSelect="True" ClientEvents-OnGridCreated="OnAllGridCreated">
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" FrozenColumnsCount="2" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True" />
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```